# Dividing the scale bar to the left of zero in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, scale-bar

I'd like to add a 2.5 km value on the left of the 0 value in my scale (divide the rectangle from 0 to 5 into two smaller ones). How to do it?

[image: scale-bar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can divide the left side of the bar by setting the first `Segment` value to `left 2`, but there is no option to add a 2.5 value.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find an option to add 2.5 value. But there may be a trick, though.

Comment: Thank You. I'll add a text label manually and it will be satisfactory.